# calculus question epislon delta

Tags: calculus, limits

let $f(x):R->R$ a function 
we know that the two following limits do exist 
 :
$lim_{x->+\infty}f(x)$

$lim_{x->-\infty}f(x)$

does $f(x)$ have max , min ? if so prove..

Comment: The formula for $f(x)$ does not appear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $f$ is not continuous this is not true. The function $f(x)=1/x$ when $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ has well defined limits in $\pm \infty$ but clearly not minimum or maximum on the line.

If, on the other hand $f$ is continuous, let $U:=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $L:=\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$, then from the definition of limits we know that there are numbers $M,N$ such that $|f(x)-U|<1$ whenever $x>M$ and $|f(x)-L|<1$ whenever $x<N$. So on the set $(-\infty,N)\cup (M,\infty)$ we can say that $|f|$ is bounded by $B_1=\max\{|U|,|L|\}+1$. What remains is the interval $[N,M]$, which is compact so $f$ assumes a maximum/minimum value and in particular $|f|$ is bounded on this interval by some $B_2$. So finally $|f|$ is bounded on all of $\mathbb{R}$ by $\max\{B_1,B_2\}$.

Note that this does not prove that $f$ also assumes its maximum value. This is not true in general.